# Edit Distance algorithm for finding minimum operations to convert one string to other

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

Lets take example, str1="ABC",str2="AFB"
To find minimum steps we consider three possibilites-
(since last letter of strings don't match)

```
1) 1+f("ABC","AF")
2) 1+f("AB","AFB")
3) 1+f("AB","AF")
```

and take minimum of the three..
My doubt is why don't we consider,  **1+f("ABC","AB")**
Please explain for a general case and not this one.Thanks.

Comment: *"we consider three possibilites [sic]"*: where do you get that decision from? Indeed, a correct algorithm will look at many more possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed many more possibilities. But the algorithm doesn't need to take them into account immediately.

The way to calculate the distance is to reduce it to smaller tasks by asking some questions and enumerating answers for them.

In your case the question probably was: **what will the optimal edit sequence do to make the last characters equal?**

There are 3 possible answers:

1. it will remove `C` from `ABC`, then we get subproblem `(AB,AFB)`
2. it will add `B` to `ABC`, then we get subproblem `(ABCB,AFB)` which is equivalent to `(ABC,AF)`
3. it will replace `C` with `B`, then we get subproblem `(ABB,AFB)` which is equivalent to `(AB,AF)`

From these options we, of course, select the shortest answer.

It's certainly possible to ask different questions, but the main idea is that we want to ask for some smaller information to reduce problem to a sequence (or a tree) of subproblems.